# Access to docs.scipy.org not possible with firefox

Tags: firefox

When I want to access docs.scipy.org with my firefox (v. 42.0) I get the error:

```
An error occurred during a connection to docs.scipy.org. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)
```

Why, and how can I fix that?
I have currently no other browsers to test it with them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox and in the address bar type:

```
about:config
```

Click the blue button that says: *I'll be careful, I promise!* to show the `about:config` page. Paste this regular expression in the Search bar at the top of the `about:config` page:

```
/security.*ssl|security.*tls/
```

If any ssl or tls Preference Name is bold (user set) then right-click that preference and choose "Reset" to reset the preference to the default value.